# Series expansion at branch cut

Tags: asymptotics, inverse-function, branch-cuts

Basically, I have obtained the function $\rho (r)$ below as a result of integrating

$$\rho(r)=\int_{b}^{r}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-(b_{0}/x)^{1-q}}}$$
which results to
$$\rho=\frac{2b}{1-q}\sqrt{1-\left(\frac br\right)^{1-q}}\,_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},\frac{q-2}{q-1},\frac{3}{2},1-\left(\frac br\right)^{1-q}\right)$$
where $b$ is just some positive constant while $-\infty<q<1$.

What I need is $r(\rho)$ which is the inverse of the function above (which I can implement with numerics). I am also interested in the series expansion of $r(\rho)$ at $\infty$ but unknowingly, the hypergeometric function above has  a branch cut at $1-\left(\frac br\right)^{1-q}=1$ (i.e. $r\rightarrow \infty$). My question would be, am I allowed to expand  $r(\rho)$ at $\infty$ given that there is a branch cut at infinity? What are the possible complications? What can I possibly do to safely obtain an asymptotic expansion of $r(\rho)$ at $\infty$? I am also thinking of converting the integral above into a differential equation for $r(\rho)$ and expand it at infinity to bypass the hypergeometric function branch cut problem but I am not really sure of this. Thanks for the help

Comment: As $|r|\to \infty$, $\rho(r)\sim r$

Comment: I am interested on the series expansion of $r(\rho)$

Comment: Yes, but that will not solve my problem. I need higher order terms though

Comment: I can find the inverse numerically, there's no problem with that. I guess my question would be if there's a complication when I obtain an asymptotic expansion of $r(\rho)$ at $\rho=\infty$ considering the branch cut at $r=\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\rho(r)=r+a+\sum_{n\ge 1} {-1/2\choose n} \frac{b_0^{n(1-q)}}{1+n(q-1)} r^{1+n(q-1)}\in r \ \Bbb{R}[[r^{-1},r^q]]^\times$$

**If $q <-1$ then**
$$\rho(r)^{-1}=r^{-1} u, \qquad u\in \Bbb{R}[[r^{-1},r^q]]^\times$$
Note that $u^{-q}=\sum_{k\ge 0} {-q\choose k} (u-1)^k\in \Bbb{R}[[r^{-1},r^q]]$.

Thus $$\phi(f(r^{-1},r^q))=f(\rho(r)^{-1},\rho(r)^q)$$ is an automorphism of $\Bbb{R}[[r^{-1},r^{q-1}]]$,
there is some $u\in \Bbb{R}[[r^{-1},r^q]]$ such that $\phi(u)=r^{-1}$.

$u^{-1}$ is your asymptotic expansion of $\rho^{-1}(r)$.

Comment: I am a bit lost with explicitly writing the form of the inverse. Can you write the first 3 terms in the inverse $r(\rho)$? Thanks

Comment: For $q\in (-2,-1)$ the inverse of $1/\rho(r^{-1})$ is $r^{-1}+c_1 r^q+c_2 r^{-2}+O(r^{-q-1})$ where the $c_j$ are found inductively. It is a mess to do it by hand.